# NinjaForm - How To Search & Retrieve By DateTime?

Tags: wordpress

I'm using NinjaForm plugin on wordpress. Here how to search and retrieve data:

```
<?php
$args = array(
  'form_id'   => $form_id,
  'user_id'   => $user_id,
  'fields'    => array(
    '34'      => 'checked',
    '54'      => 'Hello World',
  ),
);
// This will return an array of sub objects.
$subs = Ninja_Forms()->subs()->get( $args );
// This is a basic example of how to interact with the returned objects.
// See other documentation for all the methods and properties of the submission object.
foreach ( $subs as $sub ) {
  $form_id = $sub->form_id;
  $user_id = $sub->user_id;
  // Returns an array of [field_id] => [user_value] pairs
  $all_fields = $sub->get_all_fields();
  // Echoes out the submitted value for a field
  echo $sub->get_field( 34 );
}
```

What I want to do is searching by DateTime fields. How do I do that?
I have tried change args like this but result same.

```
$args = array(
  'form_id'   => 5,
  'date_modified'=> '2015-07-25 3:19:09'
);
```

or like this

```
$args = array(
  'form_id'   => 5,
  'date_modified'=> '< 2015-07-25 3:19:09'
);
```

Did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1. Find Ninja DB Table:

Go into your database using phpmyadmin or something and find the table Ninja Forms is using. Hopefully they're using their own table. If not, you can search each wp table for some of the arg data that you know returns a form from Ninja_Forms(). Or go into the Ninja plugin code and try and find where they interact with the db to find which table they write into.

2. Write your own mysql search code:

Instead of using Ninja's class to search, use wordpress's built in mysql search and throw in the table you found in step 1.

```
GLOBAL $wpdb;
$wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM `ninja_table` WHERE `date_modified` = %s", $strDate));
```

I haven't tested, but this would be my course of action.

Comment: I tried that, but the structure little bit complicated. For now, I filtered it manually. :|

Answer (score 0):

Use begin_date and end_data parameters to get the submissions

```
    $args = array(
        'form_id' => $form_id,
        'begin_date'    =>  '2015-07-20 0:00:00',
        'end_date'      => '2015-07-25 3:19:09'
    );
    $subs = Ninja_Forms()->subs()->get( $args );
```